# Time complexity analysis of minimum set cover solution

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, time-complexity

For the question

> There are n persons and k different type of dishes. Each person has
>   some preference for each dish. Either he likes it or not. We need to
>   feed all people. Every person should get atleast one dish of his
>   chioce. What is the minimum number of different type of dishes we can
>   order?

One of the solution is,

```
  public class OptimumDish {

  private Set<Integer> result = new HashSet<Integer>();

  public void print(){
    for(int r:result)
      System.out.print(r + " ");
  }

  // Find the optimum dish by navigating all available options
  public void find(int[][] m, int r, int c, int mr, int mc, Stack<Integer> dishes) {

    dishes.push(c);

    if (r == mr) {
      // Reached last person. Get the unique dishes
      Set<Integer> d = new HashSet<>(dishes);
      if(result.size() == 0 || result.size() > d.size())
        result = d;
    }
    else if (r < mr) {
      // Check next person's preferred dish
      for (int i = 0; i <= mc; i++) {
        if (m[r + 1][i] == 1) {
          find(m, r+1, i, mr, mc, dishes);
          break;
        }
      }
    }

    dishes.pop();

    // Current dish may not be the optimum.
    // Check other dish for the same person
    for (int i = c + 1; i <= mc; i++) {
      if (m[r][i] == 1) {
        find(m, r, i, mr, mc, dishes);
      }
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[][] m = { 
        { 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
        { 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0 },
        { 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0 },
        { 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0 },
        { 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0 },
        { 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1 }
        };

    int mr = m.length - 1;
    int mc = m[0].length - 1;
    int c = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i <= mr; i++) {
      if (m[0][i] == 1) {
        c = i;
        break;
      }
    }

    OptimumDish od = new OptimumDish();
    Stack<Integer> dishes = new Stack<>();
    od.find(m, 0, c, mr, mc, dishes);
    od.print();
  }
}
```

This problem is of type 'Minimum Set Cover'. Since it is a NP-Complete problem, it can't be solved in polynomial time. As per the solution it can be solved in polynomial time?

Please let me know what is the time complexity of this solution? O(n^4)?. Thanks.

Comment: Looks exponential to me. Where did the alleged bound come from?

Comment: n columns * n times (navigation of entire matrix n * n). To find one solution it takes n^3. So for n columns it is n^4. Apologies, if this is not correct. I would like to know the complexity. Thanks.